# Sul termine “tampa”

Tags: regional, single-words

“Tampa” significa “buca” o “osteria” ed è un termine marcatamente piemontese, tanto che Riccardo Regis, nella [voce “Geosinonimi” dell’*Enciclopedia dell’italiano*](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/geosinonimi_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/) lo menziona fra gli esempi di “geosinonimi di rango dialettale, a volte difformi dal sistema fonomorfologico dell'italiano, con un'estensione d'uso e di notorietà locali”, contrapposti a quelli di rango nazionale o regionale.

D'altronde Cesare Pavese lo usa in almeno due poesie per il resto in italiano standard: la giovanile “Il vino triste” (la prima di due omonime, a p. 306 dell’edizione einaudiana delle poesie), di cui riporto sotto i primi versi, e “Il tempo passa” in *Lavorare stanca*.

> È un bel fatto che tutte le volte che siedo in un angolo
>   d’una tampa a sorbire il grappino, ci sia il pederasta
>   o i bambini che strillano o il disoccupato
>   o una bella ragazza che passa di fuori,
>   tutti a rompermi il filo del fumo.

Qualcuno ha presente altri usi non dialettali, e possibilmente al di fuori del Piemonte, del termine “tampa”?

Comment: Questo link http://www.achyra.org/cruscate/viewtopic.php?p=18088 dà diverse definizioni ma non ho modo di confermarne la validità. In parecchie parti d'Italia si usa chiamare "buco" una bettola. A riguardo dell'uso di "tampa" col significato di buco in terra per rifiuti e letame (concimaia), in Basilicata la parola tampa = puzza... Chissà che non siano entrambi collegati con la parola longobarda *tampf* che ha dato origine all'italiano "tanfo" (e che l'uso tampa = concimaia non derivi dalla parola che indica l'odore piuttosto che il contrario... se poi una bettola è un buco puzzolente...).

Comment: @ErikvanDoren:  In questo [vocabolario piemontese/italiano](http://protorino.altervista.org/pdf/piemontese-base.pdf), "tampa" viene tradotta come "fossa, buca".

Comment: Perché pensi che ci siamo usi non dialettali del termine dialettale piemontese tampa? Lo stesso Pavese (piemontese) lo usa col significato dialettale.

Comment: @Charo, sì, lo so (come già detto da DaG). In un altro paio di traduttori specificano la fossa come concimaia o anche latrina. Nel link del commento si riportano 5 diversi usi della parola (si nomina il Battaglia come fonte, presuppongo ci si riferisca al "Grande dizionario della lingua italiana" che però non ho sottomano, quindi non posso confermarli). Il resto è solo una supposizione ma ho trovato curioso l'uso della parola in Basilicata e, visto che DaG chiedeva al di fuori del Piemonte...

Comment: Sì, @Josh61, quello che intendo è: Pavese usa un termine dialettale in contesti italiani (il resto di quello poesie è in italiano standard e dal link di Erik vanDoren apprendo che la parola compare anche nel romanzo *Il compagno*, in italiano). Visto che mi interessa il rapporto fra dialetti e varietà standard e come e quando termini dialettali diventano “buon italiano”, vorrei capire se qualcun altro ha usato “tampa” (nel senso usato da Pavese), magari addirittura fuori dal Piemonte.

Comment: Non essendo piemontese non mi è mai capitato di incontrare questo termine. Non l'ho mai visto usato in contesti di italiano standard (a parte le eccezioni citate di Pavese) e nessun dizionario riporta il termine, se non in senso dialettale. In regioni con cui ho familiarità come la Lombardia il Veneto e L'EmiliaRomagna non l'ho mai sentito usare.  Mi sembra che l'italianizzazione del termine sia un processo non ancora iniziato.

Comment: Grazie, @Josh61, lo sospettavo, ma mi fa piacere avere una conferma, soprattutto da regioni più vicine della mia a quella di origine del termine.

Comment: Grazie mille per l'utile link, @ErikvanDoren . Quanto al termine lucano, sospetto che sia indipendente da quello piemontese. Il *Dizionario etimologico dei dialetti italiani* di Manlio Cortellazzo e Carla Marcato dà per il “tampa” piemontese un'origine che sembra molto diversa da quella germanica (che è invece forse corretta per il termine lucano): «Da un preindoeuropeo * *tana* ‘caverna’ con il suffisso ugualmente preromano *-pa*”».

Comment: Aggiungo che esiste in Piemonte un toponimo piemontese molto simile, tampe, tamp, anche tampa, che però ha un'origine del tutto diversa. È una piemontesizzazione del francoprovenzale tchamp, cioè campo.

Ed è estremamente difficile discernere tra un'origine e l'altra se si tratta di toponimi alpini, giacché un letamaio e un campo erano e sono luoghi comuni all'alpeggio.

Solo con la conoscenza locale si può discernere, e questo avviene quando ci sono i cartelli bilingue del toponimo. Mi è capitato di vederne qualcuno in Provincia di Torino che si rifaceva espressamente al termine "campo".

Comment: Per diletto, aggiungo questa poesia piemontese, resa nota circa 2 anni dopo la pubblicazione di questo post

https://www.cordola.it/poesie-e-racconti/che-tampa/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rispondendo a me stesso: mi sono imbattuto per caso in un autore non piemontese che, in un romanzo non ambientato in Piemonte (bensì a Milano), usa il termine “tampa”.

Si tratta di Luciano Bianciardi, toscano, e del suo *La vita agra* (1962), nel cui primo capitolo si legge:

> Ogni tanto la sera io uscivo con Franz il triestino, a passeggiare per le strade dopo cena, a bere qualcosa in una tampa piena di fumo e di uomini con gli occhi rossi e il viso duro, bluastro, a cantare.